# so many means of "for" how to distinguish?

Tags: for

There's so many meanings for **"for"**
If somebody uses a short sentence and you also don't have the context how do you understand?

Example, when you say **"jump for joy"**, how do you distinguish:

> "jump if you want joy" (commanding)

from

> "I got so excited so I jumped" (voluntarily jumped)

Comment: "jump for joy" is a set phrase in English with specific meanings, which may or may not include actual "jumping". Don't take it literally.

Comment: does for ever mean "if you want", the only example i could think was "come here for pudding" but that actually mean "come here and get pudding".

Answer (score 2):

The phrase “jump for joy” pretty much means, “jump ***with*** joy,” although, as the commenter said, it often refers to figurative joy without literal jumping.

> The fans jumped for joy after their team won the championship.

If I read that sentence, I’d assume that some of the fans might have literally jumped, but others may have simply shouted and cheered instead.

---

As for your more general question (*How can you tell which meaning of “for” is intended when there are so many to choose from?*), prepositions are notoriously difficult to explain and pin down. Often, the meaning of the specific word is vague, and may even overlap with another preposition, such as *with* or *on*. For example, when I say:

> This happened for no good reason.

that’s pretty much the same as:

> This happened without a good reason.

Other times, the meaning is more idiomatic; for example, if I say:

> For the time being...

that means:

> As of right now...

I wish I could share some nugget of wisdom that unlocks this mystery, but all I can say is that you’ve identified a thorny challenge for learners: there’s no reliable, magic way to figure out which of the dictionary’s several meanings will map to the one you’ve stumbled across.